# Is this correct usage of "pursue a degree"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Is the following sentence correct? If no, how should I say this sentence correctly?  Many Thanks.

> My excellent mathematical skills led me to pursue a mathematics and physics diploma.

Comment: You're [much more likely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pursue+a+diploma%2Cpursue+a+degree&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpursue%20a%20diploma%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpursue%20a%20degree%3B%2Cc0) to *pursue a degree* than to *pursue a diploma*, but that's probably just because more people write about studying for degrees than for diplomas. I don't see why you would need to ask here about the "validity" of either form though.

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers for the comment. In my country, after finishing high school, students receive diploma such as mathematics and physics diploma. I don't know about other countries. About second part of your comment, I misunderstand a paragraph in the link.

Comment: It might be worth noting that ***pursuing** a degree / diploma / course / etc.* essentially refers to the ***process*** (of ***following / studying*** the course), rather than "chasing after" the end result (the ***certificate itself**, or the ***awarding*** of it upon successful completion).

Comment: @jsw29 thanks for the comment. I think high school diploma is common. But I don't that can I use it with pursue in the sentence?

Comment: If one is writing for English speakers who are unfamiliar with the educational system in this country, the least confusing thing is likely to be something like 'in high school, I concentrated on mathematics and physics'.

Comment: @jsw29 1. You refer to "the educational system in this country". Which country? UK, USA, AUS, NZ, etc. - you could be from any of them!  2. Your statement "the least confusing thing is likely to be something like 'in high school" is unclear because we do not know what country you are referring to.  The term "high school" is no longer common in England since the schooling system was changed many years ago.  And as we do not know which country Op is referring to, we cannot know whether your suggestion is appropriate.

Comment: @TrevorD 'This country' refers to whichever country Mr. Nobody referred to as 'my country' in his earlier comment. I have no idea which specific country that is, but it appears that it is not an English-speaking country; otherwise the problem wouldn't arise. *High school* is a term used by Mr. Nobody himself; I did not suggest that he change it, as it is still sufficiently well known throughout the English-speaking world not to be misleading. The point of my comment was that it may be better to speak of concentrating on a particular area than saying than one has a particular kind of a diploma.

Comment: @jsw29 Your comment reads to me as if you were referring to your own country, since you wrote "**this** country". Mr.N. wrote "in **my** country": if you were referring to that country, then I would have expected you to write "**your** country".  "**This** country" generally refers to the country that one is currently in  and that's how I read your comment.